# data on maintenance costs in EPC sector

Tags: uses-of-open-data

I have to do a PoC on PowerBI for predictive maintenance (both for unscheduled and scheduled maintenance).

I saw this article about fluor and am looking for open data that would allow to discover similar insights : https://www.nsenergybusiness.com/news/fluor-to-deploy-ibm-watson-for-predictive-analytics-capability-for-epc-projects/

Do you happen to know any EPC (O&G, roads, tunnel, bridges, etc) 'asset management'/ "maintenance cost' dataset  ? Alternatively, it could be also facility management.

I came across a lot "predictive maintenance" dataset for manufacturing. It is mostly about fault fetection. Here we are more looking into maintenance cost, rather that "fault detection".

I don't know at all the EPC business, so any suggestion would be more than welcome!